# Trying to use nested for loop to correctly parse nested list items

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

I have a nested list (derived from a psycopg2 psql query) that contains a list of company names, stock tickers, and industries. I am using a subsequent nested for loop to try and extract the 1st (company name) and 3rd (industry) elements from the nested list rows in subsequent print statements.

In this example, the company name is American Airlines, the stock ticker is AAL, and the industry is Airlines.

postgreSQL query:

```
# psycopg2 query to pull company name and industry based on stock ticker
  cur.execute('SELECT company,stockTicker,industry FROM stockNames WHERE 
  stockTicker = %s',(stockChoice,))
  records=cur.fetchall()
```

My current nested for loop is as follows:

```
for i in records:
     for j in i:
          count=0
          if count==0:
               print('\n' 'Company Name: ',j)
               print('Stock Ticker: ',stockChoice)
               continue
          if count==1:
               continue
          if count==2:               
               print('Industry: ',list,j)
               print('Stock Price: ',stockPrice.text)
               continue
          count+=1
```

And the output is:

```
Company Name:  American Airlines
Stock Ticker:  AAL

Company Name:  AAL
Stock Ticker:  AAL

Company Name:  Airlines
Stock Ticker:  AAL
```

My expected output is this:

```
Company Name: American Airlines
Stock Ticker: AAL
Industry: Airlines
```

Any help on this is appreciated to get the control flow right for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You do `count=0` every time through the nested loop. It's always `0` when you check its value.

Comment: @Woodford Do you have any recommendations how I could make the 2nd printed j be the value of the 3rd-iterated j value? It's what I'm trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. The simplest change to your code would be to move the line `count=0` up one line so you reset the value before the nested loop instead of within it.

Comment: There's no need for the inner loop. Just access the columns by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use nested loops. Just unpack each row into variables

```
for company, ticker, industry in records:
    print(f'Company name: {company}\nStock ticker: {ticker}\nIndustry: {industry}\n')
```

And if you're only getting the information for one stock, there's no need for the loop at all.

```
cur.execute('SELECT company,stockTicker,industry FROM stockNames WHERE stockTicker = %s',(stockChoice,))
row = cur.fetchone()
if row:
    company, ticker, industry = row
    print(f'Company name: {company}\nStock ticker: {ticker}\nIndustry: {industry}\n')
```